# How to move an existing Line shape in java using a mouse?

Tags: java, javafx, shapes

I would like to drag a selected line, but I'm unsure how to do it.
I tried the following but it doesn't work and the line doesn't move correctly. What calculations am I missing?

```
var deltaX = mouseEvent.x - (line.startX + line.endX)
var deltaY = mouseEvent.y - (line.startY + line.endY)
line.startX  = line.startX + deltaX
line.startY  = line.startY +deltaY
line.endX = line.endX + deltaX
line.endY = line.endY +deltaY
```

Comment: Is it java or kotlin? Please change tags

Comment: deleted the Kotlin tag

Answer (score 4):

[image: moving line javafx]

**moving line with mouse**

moving a line using mouse event

App.java

```
    public class App extends Application {

    private double startX;
    private double startY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Line line = new Line(0, 0, 0, 200);
        line.setStrokeWidth(8);
        Shape endHandler = new Circle(15, Color.BLUE);

        endHandler.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        line.setOnMousePressed(e -> {

            startX = line.getLayoutX() - e.getX();
            startY = line.getLayoutY() - e.getY();

        });

        line.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            line.setTranslateX(line.getTranslateX() + e.getX()+startX);
            line.setTranslateY(line.getTranslateY() + e.getY()+startY);

        });

        Group group = new Group(line);
        group.setTranslateX(250);
        group.setTranslateY(250);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new AnchorPane(group), 500, 500);

        stage.setTitle("moving line");

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**moving by binding start x y and end x y**

[image: moving line]

In this aproach we are dragging circle shapes and the start and the end of line object will  follow  those shapes 'cause they are binded
This is a functional single javafx app you can try .
red circle is for start line position and blue is for end

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Line line = new Line(0, 0, 0, 200);
        Shape endHandler = new Circle(15, Color.BLUE);

        endHandler.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        Shape startHandler = new Circle(15, Color.RED);

        startHandler.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

        endHandler.translateXProperty().bindBidirectional(line.endXProperty());
        endHandler.translateYProperty().bindBidirectional(line.endYProperty());

        startHandler.translateXProperty().bindBidirectional(line.startXProperty());
        startHandler.translateYProperty().bindBidirectional(line.startYProperty());

        endHandler.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            endHandler.setTranslateX(endHandler.getTranslateX() + e.getX());
            endHandler.setTranslateY(endHandler.getTranslateY() + e.getY());

        });
        startHandler.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            startHandler.setTranslateX(startHandler.getTranslateX() + e.getX());
            startHandler.setTranslateY(startHandler.getTranslateY() + e.getY());

        });

        Group group = new Group(line, endHandler, startHandler);
        group.setTranslateX(250);
        group.setTranslateY(250);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new AnchorPane(group), 500, 500);

        stage.setTitle("moving line");

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry perhaps I should have phrased my question better, I have a line which I need to drag using the mouse. i.e not change the line itself but just change its position on the pane

Comment: so , it is like drag and drop any object

Comment: yes similar to that, just drag the line and drop it somewhere on the pane

Answer (score 0):

This code cancels out the start / end position.
for

```
line.startX  = line.startX + deltaX
=
line.startX  = line.startX +(mouseEvent.x - (line.startX + line.endX))
= 
line.startX  = -line.endX+mouseEvent.x
```

So now you dont even have the start position

You should have

```
var deltaX=mouseEvent.x
var deltaY = mouseEvent.y
line.startX  = line.startX + deltaX
line.startY  = line.startY +deltaY
line.endX = line.endX + deltaX
line.endY = line.endX +deltaY
```

Make sure the mouse Positions update

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, the line seems to disappear from the drawing area completely

Comment: I would try using some debugging. Check that the mouse Positions are valid and in the right spot. Other than that it should work

Comment: they are valid, but I think simply adding the mouse portion doesn't seem right. I will try debugging

Comment: Also make sure the container (Pane, AnchorPane etc) that you are placing the line object into isn't trying to manage its position. Some Pane types by default manage the position of their children.  If you find that is the case you can either change the Pane type or explicitly disable this behavior with line.setManaged(false).